# Table of subfloats

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, subfloats, sorting

I'm trying to sort figures (using subfloat) in a table, with labels for each subfigure. My point is, using only subfloat, that the subfigures are referred in the text as figure a, b, ... and so on.
But I'd like to sort them in column too, so that they will be referred as 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, ...

Is there a way to do that using the `subfig` package (through the subfloat command)? Or is there another package?

EDIT: The solution does not completely do what I would like ... Here is some precision. I would like to have two kind of figures: the one where each subfloat is different, and has its own "number", and the one where subfloats have to be sorted by column and row.

Here is an example based on the first answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,listofformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{subfigRow}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newRow}{\refstepcounter{subfigRow}\setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{subfigRow}{1}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{parens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}
\DeclareSubrefFormat{parens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}
\DeclareCaptionListOfFormat{parens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
1 &
\subfloat{\label{one}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{two}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{three}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}\\
\newRow
2 &
\subfloat{\label{four}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{five}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{six}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}\\
 & (a) & (b) & (c)
\end{tabular}
\caption{A bunch of figures}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{seven}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{eight}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{nine}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{ten}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{11}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{12}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\caption{Another bunch of figures}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}
As seen in \subref{one} and \subref{six} of Figure~\ref{fig:first} and
\subref{eight} of Figure~\ref{fig:second}
\end{document}
```

that gives [image]

My point is to have the number removed in the second case.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "sort"? Do you want LaTeX to re-arrange the subfigures?

Comment: Hi Werner! Thanks for the answer. No, by 'sorting', I mean that I want to be able to refer to a subfigure using its position in columns and rows. For now, the subfloat command allows me to have a letter assigned to each subfigure. I would like to have a number (in reference of the subfigure raw) and a letter (in reference of the column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I just needed to adapt the solution from @Alan Munn, and change some of the `subfig` package options. So here is the final solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[lofdepth, subrefformat=subparens]{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{subfigRow}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newRow}{\refstepcounter{subfigRow}\setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{subfigRow}{1}}

\DeclareSubrefFormat{subparens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
1 &
\subfloat{\label{one}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{two}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{three}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}\\
\newRow
2 &
\subfloat{\label{four}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{five}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}} &
\subfloat{\label{six}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}\\
 & (a) & (b) & (c)
\end{tabular}
\caption{A bunch of figures}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{seven}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{eight}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{nine}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{ten}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{11}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{12}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\caption{Another bunch of figures}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}
As seen in \subref*{one} and \subref*{six} of Figure~\ref{fig:first} and
\subref{eight} of Figure~\ref{fig:second}
\end{document}
```

And it gives [image]

Thanks for your input ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to do it semi-automatically.  We define a new counter for the row number; each time you add a row of subfigures you use the `\newRow` command to increment the row counter and reset the subfigure counter.  I've also added code to format the captions in the list of figures and the references to show how the whole thing would work together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,listofformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{subfigRow}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newRow}{\refstepcounter{subfigRow}\setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{subfigRow}{1}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{parens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}
\DeclareSubrefFormat{parens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}
\DeclareCaptionListOfFormat{parens}{(\thesubfigRow#2)}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[htb]
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{one}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{two}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{three}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad

\newRow
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{four}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{five}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{six}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\caption{A bunch of figures}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{seven}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{eight}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{nine}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\newRow
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{ten}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{11}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\subfloat[A subcaption][A subcaption\label{12}]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=.25in]{foo}}
\qquad
\caption{Another bunch of figures}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}
As seen in \subref{one} and \subref{six} of Figure~\ref{fig:first} and
\subref{eight} of Figure~\ref{fig:second}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1: I think this is what the OP wants. I don't envy anyone trying to read the document though...

Comment: @cmhughes I agree; a sequential list is probably easier. But if the references are all quite local (as I've done them) and the subfigures *aren't* listed in the LoF, it may be not so bad.

Comment: @Alan Munn : Thanks! It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Gnesson: I converted your answer into a comment, as it's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thanks. I wasn't able to comment because of an account mix up.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you want?

[image: screenshot]

I have used the `subcaption` package, combined with `minipages`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
    \rule{20pt}{30pt}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
    \rule{20pt}{30pt}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:subfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
    \rule{20pt}{30pt}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
    \rule{20pt}{30pt}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:subfig4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:subfig1}, \ref{fig:subfig2}, \ref{fig:subfig3}, \ref{fig:subfig4}

\end{document}
```